# How to disable Explorer search history?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

At least the three last search strings are saved:

[image]

I've disabled the history settings I'm aware of:

[image]

Comment: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-disable-autocomplete-inline-autocomplete-windows-explorer-internet-explorer

Comment: @vincentkleine: The article appears to be outdated, compare `internet options` > `advanced`: https://i.imgur.com/KYSQOJ9.png

Comment: SE Imgur URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3btlq.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute command in the elevated command prompt:

```
REG Delete HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\WordWheelQuery /VA /F
```

Comment: Can you please provide a source link from where you obtained this command?

Comment: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6719-clear-search-history-windows-10-file-explorer.html

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). You also need to [edit] your answer and add the source link.

Comment: I posted this command in 2009 on technet forums. Plagiarism are on tenforums.

Comment: "I posted this command in 2009 on technet forums" Then you should reference that as your source.